# Doesn't on synchronization, multithreaading become non - multithreading? Then why do multithreading in the first place?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Multithreading is when multiple threads execute concurrently. But, when the threads are synchronized, multi - threading does not happen. They work as normal thread. Then why do multithreading in the first place, if we have to synchronize it anyways?

Comment: You only synchronize critical sections which must be executed mutually exclusively.

Comment: If you synchronized using one lock absolutely everything it would be pointless which is why you wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're synchronizing your threads in the way that you describe then there's no point in multithreading. One place where you WOULD use multithreading would be parallel data processing. After you collect all necessary input you can run the threads independently of eachother without need for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You don't synchronize so that you end up with threads never executing in parallel, rather you synchronize so that *certain* parts of the code are not executed in parallel.

Imagine two threads progressively reading values from a shared array, running some computation on them and then adding the result into a shared memory location.

The part with reading values needs synchronization to make sure that no two threads read the same value.

The part with adding the data into the memory location should be synchronized so the data is not being written by both threads at the same time.

The part with the computation can be done in parallel, and usually this part will be the most time consuming. Thus, this is how you benefit from multithreading.